# Invalid syntax at colon in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't seem to determine which part of the code is the cause of invalid syntax.

```py
for date in tqdm(iterable = dates, unit="image", desc=f"Downloading {len(dates)} images", disable = False if show_progress > 0):
    get_image(
        scale=scale,
        level=level,
        retries=retries,
        multithread=multithread,
        nthread=nthread,
        save_img=save_img,
        img_path=img_path,
        img_name=img_name.replace("{prefix}", prefix).replace("{date}", date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")),
        show_progress=True if show_progress > 1,
        date=date)
```

pylint shows invalid syntax at the colon

```
invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1) [1, 128]
```

but when i ran the code, syntax error is at the parentheses

```
    for date in tqdm(iterable = dates, unit="image", desc=f"Downloading {len(dates)} images", disable = False if show_progress > 0):
                                                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Where exactly are my mistakes?

Comment: What is the data structure of tqdm?

Comment: tqdm is just a decorator for iterator which shows a progress bar. tqdm iterates dates which is a list. I've tried only using `dates` but the syntax error moves to end of `show_progress=True if show_progress > 1,`

Answer (score 3):

The syntax error is because you have an incomplete ternary expression: `disable = False if show_progress > 0`

A ternary expression must have `<value> if <condition> else <othervalue>` so in your case `False if show_progress > 0 else True`

that said, there's also [no need for a ternary expression when both ends are booleans](https://github.com/asottile/scratch/wiki/PythonHintsForNoobs#useless-branches), just use `disable = show_progress <= 0`

Comment: Thank you for the last one, didnt know that one before

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop iterator function tqdm, there is a syntax error in the last keyword argument "disable". The if...else condition is not complete.

```
disable = False if show_progress > 0
```

This should be something like below.

```
disable = False if show_progress > 0 else True
```

Comment: the syntax error now moves to end comma at `show_progress=True if show_progress > 1,`

Comment: Ah wait, i got it. i forgot the other one